# DROP TABLE or DELETE TABLE? Which is best practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working on redesigning some databases in my SQL SERVER 2012 instance.

I have databases where I put my raw data (from vendors) and then I have client databases where I will (based on client name) create a view that only shows data for a specific client.

Because of the this data being volatile (Google Adwords & Google DFA) I typically just delete the last 6 days and insert 7 days everyday from the vendor databases. Doing this gives me comfort in knowing that Google has had time to solidify its data.

The question I am trying to answer is:

  1. Instead of using views, would it be better use a 'SELECT INTO' statement and DROP the table everyday in the client database?

I'm afraid that by automating my process using the 'DROP TABLE' method will not scale well longterm. While testing it myself, it seems that performance is improved because it does not have to scan the entire table for the date range. I've also tested this with an index on the 'date' column and performance still seemed better with the 'DROP TABLE' method.

I am looking for best practices here.

NOTE: This is my first post. So I am not too familiar with how to format correctly. :)

Comment: Your question is not one that will generate hard facts. It will generate mostly opinions and as such is deemed out of scope for this site. Your question is also very vague.

Comment: Dropping table will loose the indexes and stats, which will decrese the performance on the long run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deleting rows from a table is a time-consuming process.  All the deleted records get logged, and performance of the server suffers.

Instead, databases offer `truncate table`.  This removes all the rows of the table *without logging the rows*, but keeps the structure intact.  Also, triggers, indexes, constraints, stored procedures, and so on are not affected by the removal of rows.

In some databases, if you delete all rows from a table, then the operation is really `truncate table`.  However, SQL Server is not one of those databases.  In fact the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) lists `truncate` as a best practice for deleting all rows:

> To delete all the rows in a table, use `TRUNCATE TABLE`. `TRUNCATE TABLE`
>   is faster than `DELETE` and uses fewer system and transaction log
>   resources. `TRUNCATE TABLE` has restrictions, for example, the table
>   cannot participate in replication. For more information, see `TRUNCATE
>   TABLE` (Transact-SQL)

You can drop the table.  But then you lose auxiliary metadata as well -- all the things listed above.

I would recommend that you truncate the table and reload the data using `insert into` or `bulk insert`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and easy to grasp answer! Kudos!

Comment: A thing to note with `truncate table` is that the table which will be truncated cannot be referenced as a foreign key to other tables or those references are needed to be dropped before truncation.